# Error edit image using entity Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I have a problem editing an article.  I have an error when I want to edit an image.  Here is my entity:

```
namespace Article\ArticleBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Article
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

      /**
     * @var string $image
     * @Assert\File( maxSize = "1024k", mimeTypesMessage = "Please upload a valid Image")
     * @ORM\Column(name="image", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $image;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set image
     *
     * @param string $image
     * @return Article
     */
    public function setImage($image)
    {
        $this->image = $image;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get image
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getImage()
    {
        return $this->image;
    }

      public function getFullImagePath() {
        return null === $this->image ? null : $this->getUploadRootDir(). $this->image;
    }

    protected function getUploadRootDir() {
        // the absolute directory path where uploaded documents should be saved
        return $this->getTmpUploadRootDir().$this->getId()."/";
    }

    protected function getTmpUploadRootDir() {
        // the absolute directory path where uploaded documents should be saved
        return __DIR__ . '/../../../../web/upload/';
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     * @ORM\PreUpdate()
     */
    public function uploadImage() {
        // the file property can be empty if the field is not required
        if (null === $this->image) {
            return;
        }
        if(!$this->id){
            $this->image->move($this->getTmpUploadRootDir(), $this->image->getClientOriginalName());
        }else{
            $this->image->move($this->getUploadRootDir(), $this->image->getClientOriginalName());
        }
        $this->setImage($this->image->getClientOriginalName());
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PostPersist()
     */
    public function moveImage()
    {
        if (null === $this->image) {
            return;
        }
        if(!is_dir($this->getUploadRootDir())){
            mkdir($this->getUploadRootDir());
        }
        copy($this->getTmpUploadRootDir().$this->image, $this->getFullImagePath());
        unlink($this->getTmpUploadRootDir().$this->image);
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PreRemove()
     */
    public function removeImage()
    {
        unlink($this->getFullImagePath());
        rmdir($this->getUploadRootDir());
    }
}
```

This is the code of my form:

```
namespace Article\ArticleBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;

class ArticleType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('image')
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Article\ArticleBundle\Entity\Article'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'article_articlebundle_article';
    }
}
```

This the controller:

```
namespace Article\ArticleBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

use Article\ArticleBundle\Entity\Article;
use Article\ArticleBundle\Form\ArticleType;

/**
 * Article controller.
 */
class ArticleController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Lists all Article entities.
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entities = $em->getRepository('ArticleArticleBundle:Article')->findAll();

        return $this->render('ArticleArticleBundle:Article:index.html.twig', array(
            'entities' => $entities,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new Article entity.
     */
    public function createAction(Request $request)
    {
        $entity = new Article();
        $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('article_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
        }

        return $this->render('ArticleArticleBundle:Article:new.html.twig', array(
            'entity' => $entity,
            'form'   => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Creates a form to create a Article entity.
     *
     * @param Article $entity The entity
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
     */
    private function createCreateForm(Article $entity)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(new ArticleType(), $entity, array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('article_create'),
            'method' => 'POST',
        ));

        $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Create'));

        return $form;
    }

    /**
     * Displays a form to create a new Article entity.
     */
    public function newAction()
    {
        $entity = new Article();
        $form   = $this->createCreateForm($entity);

        return $this->render('ArticleArticleBundle:Article:new.html.twig', array(
            'entity' => $entity,
            'form'   => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Finds and displays a Article entity.
     */
    public function showAction($id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entity = $em->getRepository('ArticleArticleBundle:Article')->find($id);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Article entity.');
        }

        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

        return $this->render('ArticleArticleBundle:Article:show.html.twig', array(
            'entity'      => $entity,
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Displays a form to edit an existing Article entity.
     */
    public function editAction($id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entity = $em->getRepository('ArticleArticleBundle:Article')->find($id);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Article entity.');
        }

        $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

        return $this->render('ArticleArticleBundle:Article:edit.html.twig', array(
            'entity'      => $entity,
            'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Creates a form to edit a Article entity.
     *
     * @param Article $entity The entity
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
     */
    private function createEditForm(Article $entity)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(new ArticleType(), $entity, array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('article_update', array('id' => $entity->getId())),
            'method' => 'PUT',
        ));

        $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Update'));

        return $form;
    }

    /**
     * Edits an existing Article entity.
     */
    public function updateAction(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entity = $em->getRepository('ArticleArticleBundle:Article')->find($id);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Article entity.');
        }

        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
        $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
        $editForm->handleRequest($request);

        if ($editForm->isValid()) {
           $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('article_edit', array('id' => $id)));
        }

        return $this->render('ArticleArticleBundle:Article:edit.html.twig', array(
            'entity'      => $entity,
            'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Deletes a Article entity.
     */
    public function deleteAction(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $form = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entity = $em->getRepository('ArticleArticleBundle:Article')->find($id);

            if (!$entity) {
                throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Article entity.');
            }

            $em->remove($entity);
            $em->flush();
        }

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('article'));
    }

    /**
     * Creates a form to delete a Article entity by id.
     *
     * @param mixed $id The entity id
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
     */
    private function createDeleteForm($id)
    {
        return $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->setAction($this->generateUrl('article_delete', array('id' => $id)))
            ->setMethod('DELETE')
            ->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Delete'))
            ->getForm()
        ;
    }
}
```

This the error that appears:

> The form's view data is expected to be an instance of class Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File, but is a(n) string. You can avoid this error by setting the "data_class" option to null or by adding a view transformer that transforms a(n) string to an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File.

Comment: You have far too much code for people to sift through - you should only post the relevant parts, not sections to create/delete entities that have nothing to do with your question.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use same Entity property for a file (not persisted to the database) and file path (persisted). You can find a tutorial at [Symfony Cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html).